# Ramban and the generations

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, commentaries, kohelet, ramban

I heard someone mention the folowing:

The Ramban in the writings on sefer koheles make an interesting *diyuk*. *Koheles* (1:4) tell us, “A generation goes and a generation comes.” The Ramban tell us that posuk should have stated, “A generation comes and a generation goes?” The Ramban quoting the Medrasho shel ר' נחוניא בן הקנה:
אמר רבי עקיבא דור בא שכבר בא בגלגול שעבר. The Ramban refers to this as the Sod Ha’Iber, which is the Sod HaGilgul.

1. Does anyone know where the Ramban gets his question from?
2. Does anyone where the text of אמר רבי עקיבא דור בא שכבר בא בגלגול שעבר, can be found?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Would you like to know [1] where the Ramban says this or [2] how the Ramban knew this to be the case?

Comment: @Shokhet: 1 and 2.

Comment: It's in the Ramban's drasha על דברי קהלת. (though it's **Nechunyah** ben HaKaneh)

Comment: @Matt: Can you send me a link to it and what page it's on?

Comment: Third line, here: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38545&st=&pgnum=10&hilite=

Comment: I didn't post this as an answer though, because the Ramban only hints to the question and doesn't state it explicitly

Answer (score 3):

This appears in Ramban's Derashah Al Divrei Kohelet:

> ויש לרבותינו בפסוק הזה שאלה שהקשו שיאמר דור בא ודור הולך והשיבו בזה סוד גדול מן הסודות הנכללות בכלל סוד העיבור והוא מדרשו של ר' נחוניא בן הקנה כמו שהזכרתי כי דברי שלמה כפולים ומכופלים בחכמה

Here is an image of the passage in Kitvei Ramban Vol. I (Mossad Harav Kook, Jerusalem 1963):

[image: Image of text of Kitvei Ramban]

It is based on a passage in [Sefer Habahir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahir):

> מאי דור דור אמר ר' פפייס דור הולך ודור בא ואמר ר' עקיבא דור בא שכבר בא

Here is an image of the passage in the Mossad Harav Kook edition (Jerusalem 1951):

[image: Image of text in Sefer Habahir]

Note that neither source expressly mentions "gilgul". However, in the commentary Ohr Haganuz to the Sefer Habahir by one of the students of [Rashba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_ibn_Aderet), it is expressly identified as "gilgul":

> מאי דור דור. שכבר בא בגלגול שעבר לפי שקלקל מעשיו בא לעולם לתקן עוותו

Here is an image of that commentary from the aforementioned edition:

[image: Image of text of Ohr Haganuz commentary]